Is it 'de mortibus nihil nisi bonum/bene', or is it 'de mortuis nihil nisi bonum/bene'?
I distinctly remember that, back in Grammar school, we were taught 'de mortibus nihil nisi bonum/bene' (I don't want to go into the 'bonum/bene' discussion here). I don't google, because of privacy concerns, but I 'startpage' and when I startpage 'de mortibus nihil nisi bonum/bene', I only get 'de mortuis etc.' Did I miss out on something? Is it 'de mortuis', or 'de mortibus'?

You might be mixing up de mortuis with another popular phrase: de gustibus non est disputandum.

It is definitely de mortuis, because mortuus is the Latin word for "dead." It is actually the past participle of mori (meaning "deceased," see Lewis & Short), and past participles are, of course, always inflected according to the first/second declension. No -ibus there.
Mors, mortis, f. on the other hand means "death," so de mortibus nil nisi bene would mean "say only good things about deaths." I'm not sure anybody would share this sentiment, but in any case that's not what this adage is supposed to express.
